# System not defined when upgrading to Angular2

Tags: angular

As per the official [guidelines](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) on upgrading an angular1 app to angular2 you need to include the `system.src.js` file and then load the application in like so:

```
    System.config({
      packages: {'js': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
    });
    System.import('/js/app.module');
```

This points to an expected `app.module.ts` file that is the main component of the application. However this code isn't even getting this far as it complains:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Which made me think that it isn't loading the `system.src.js` file correctly. But I've tried loading it via gulp, which concats and places all my js files into one file i.e. `main.js` - no success, and I've tried including it seperately e.g.

```
dist
    js
        main.js
        system.src.js
```

and adding a script tag for this version:

```
// Loaded before the import statement above so it's definitely there
%script{src: "js/system.src.js", async: true}
%script{src: "js/main.js", async: true}
```

but neither of these ways actually work. I can even see it as a source file in the dev window so it's there - so am I missing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your tsconfig?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This was actually part of the problem - part of the problem was that it wasn't properly reloading when I modified some of my files. Cheers and onwards to the next upgrade problem